# Alter query for sigle.php if the post is in wordpress specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a category on my site called `cat-name`. I need to change the query on `single.php` if the current post is on that category.

**Why I need that?** Because have a `custom field` called `posts_ids` where I keep an array (`$arrayIds`) of the posts ID that I want to show on `single.php`

I don't know if this is possible, but I hope I was clear on my needs...

**This is what I have so far:**

```
    function target_my_category_query ( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category() && $query->in_category('cat-name')) {

            $postIds = get_post_meta(the_ID(), 'posts_ids', true);
            $arrayIds = explode(',', $postIds);         
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
            $query->set( 'post__in', $arrayIds);
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'orderby' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'order');
            $query->set( 'post__not_in', get_option('sticky_posts'));           
            $query->set( 'meta_query',  array('0' => array('key' => 'cfvna', 'value' => 'true', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS')));           
        }
            
    }

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'target_my_category_query ' );
```

Comment: `$query->is_category()` checks if you are on a category archive page, so if you want to target the query for a single post to be display on the single.php, that is completely wrong to begin with.

Comment: `$postIds = get_post_meta(the_ID(), 'posts_ids', true);` - that `the_ID()` gets you the ID of the post that the single.php is currently getting invoked for here, is also very unlikely - according to the documentation, that function only works within "the loop". WP_Query has a `$queried_object_id` property (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties), that one should contain the ID of your post here.

Comment: `$query->set( 'post__in', $arrayIds);` - with that you would be excluding the post that the single.php was invoked for here in the first place (unless you had the post's own ID stored in its own `posts_ids` meta as well), not sure if that is desired. If not, then you'd need to add the post ID to this array.